# DS3218MG Servo - Not working with power supply

Tags: arduino-nano, power, servo

I'm trying to run my **DS3218MG Servo Motor** with an external power supply and my arduino nano.

I'm using the following code:

```
#include<Servo.h>
Servo Myservo;
int pos;
void setup()
{
Myservo.attach(3);
}

void loop()
{
  
  
for(pos=0;pos<=180;pos++){
Myservo.write(pos);
delay(15);
}
  delay(1000);
  
  for(pos=180;pos>=0;pos--){
Myservo.write(pos);
delay(15);
}
  delay(1000);
```

}

According to the datasheet the servo needs a **DC 4.8-6.8** voltage. My first attempt was to only use the arduino and no external power supply. So did the following connections:

- servo's **ground** to arduino's **ground**
- servo's **+** to arduino's **5V**
- servo's **data** to arduino's GPIO **pin** 3

Using this connection works fine and the servo rotatates to the desired positions. However, because the arduino does not supply enough current, i bought a power supply with the following specs:

[image]

With that, i did the following connections:

- connect the **ground** of the power supply to arduino's **ground** (and servo)
- keep the **data** pin
- connect **+** of power supply to servo's **+**

[image]

Unfortunately, the servo does not move with the external power supply. IMO, it should have the right voltage and also supply enough current (at least as much as the Arduino).

Do you see the problem?

Comment: How are you powering the Arduino in the new setup?

Comment: regular usb cable for powering arduino

Comment: I would set the external power supply to 5V (your photo shows 6V) and try to measure the voltage of the servo while the Arduino is attempting to move it. Your servo is a high current device, which is not really suitable for connecting to a breadboard.

Comment: but 6 V should be fine since the servo allows DC 4.8-6.8 shouldn't it? However, nothing happens with 5v either - also when i directly connect the power +  to the servo +  instead of using a breadboard. How do I measure voltage of servo while arduino is attempting to move it?

Comment: Except you're interfacing a 5V device to it, which might or might not cause problems when running the servo at 6V (probably not, but the servo works at 5V either way). Did you measure the voltage on the servo's pins when you're trying to move it?

Comment: how can i measure this? do you mean the voltage from the power supply?

Comment: I mean measure the supply voltage going into the servo, as close to the servo as possible, to see if the breadboard is causing an issue (bad contacts, high resistance).

Comment: but as I said before, I also tried to remove the breadboard and solder the connections directly i.e. solder the + of the power to + of the servo. Shouldn't it actually work with that?

Answer (score 1):

@starcat,  regular  usb cable for  powering  arduino